# Creating a digraph with formulas instead of nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, arrows, nodes

I am looking to make a diagram with lines similar to this one: [Labeling Edges in a Weighted Digraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127534/labeling-edges-in-a-weighted-digraph)

But I am trying to have a mathematical formula, which is the label, instead of being above the dot nodes, replace the thick dot nodes. In other words the lines don't actually connect, but like those in commutative diagrams. This method allows location of nodes to be precisely specified, slightly different from tikz-cd.

How?

How to do this in tikz-cd is also helpful.

How does one make the node to label arrows and cutting of arrows by overlapping arrows in this framework?

[ ... question was tidied up after being answered and size of arrowheads and labels question placed in its own question ... My own MWE example moved to that question for those corrections, [Changing Size of Arrows, Labels, Loops in Diagrams and Directed Graphs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127670/changing-size-of-arrows-labels-loops-in-diagrams-and-directed-graphs), since the answer has several MWEs that answer original question.]

Comment: Have you looked at the `amscd` package?  It is for commutative diagrams.

Comment: Might be just as easy to use plain TikZ. Are you familiar with that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format

Comment: I am familiar with making simple commuting diagrams using tikz-cd package, but the use of vertexes defined in the way the linked example was written, and curves defined in that way makes my life so much easier with all my nonlinear diagrams, if only I could figure out how to use this coding for commutative style diagrams.

Comment: @user34902 please see my updated answer.

Comment: @user34902 Sorry; this is a place in which we like to keep things tidy; ideally **one** question per post. I can't be all day editing my answer and adding information every time you come up with new requirements. I think my answer below satisfies your initial requirements; for further issues, please open a fresh new question.

Comment: Yes. I have marked my question as answered by your post and will start a new question with the font size question. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the powerful [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) package you can easily create commutative diagrams with curved arrows; a little example (the package documentation contains other examples); notice the `swap` option to change the position of labels:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=3cm,column sep=2cm,shorten >= 4pt,shorten <=4pt]
F(x)
  \arrow[bend left=40]{r}{F(f)}[name=UF,below]{}
  \arrow[bend right=40]{r}[swap]{F(g)}[name=DF]{}
  \arrow[bend left=30]{d}{A(x)}[name=D1,below]{}
  \arrow[bend right=30]{d}[swap]{B(x)}[name=D2]{}
& F(y) 
  \arrow[bend left=30]{d}{A(y)}[name=D3,below]{}
  \arrow[bend right=30]{d}[swap]{B(y)}[name=D4]{} \\
G(x)
  \arrow[bend left=40]{r}{G(f)}[name=UG,below]{}
  \arrow[bend right=40]{r}[swap]{G(g)}[name=DG]{}
& G(y) \\
\arrow[Rightarrow,to path=(UF) -- (DF)]{}
\arrow[Rightarrow,to path=(UG) -- (DG)]{}
\arrow[Rightarrow,shorten <=10pt,to path=(D1|-D2) -- (D2)]{}
\arrow[Rightarrow,shorten <=10pt,to path=(D3|-D4) -- (D4)]{}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Addendum: After the edit to the question:

You can still use "pure" `TikZ` in combination to `tikz-cd`; this gives you the possibility to achieve manual positioning (as was required) as well as to have consistency with the arrow and label style from `tikz-cd`.

For the crossing over edges, `tikz-cd` offers the `crossing over` style for `\arrow` (see first example below) and `TikZ` offers also mechanisms to achieve the same effect (second example below):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=scriptsize, column sep=scriptsize]
& f^* E_V \arrow{dl}\arrow{rr}\arrow{dd} & & E_V \arrow{dl}\arrow{dd} \\
f^* E \arrow[crossing over]{rr}\arrow{dd} & & E \\
& U \arrow{dl}\arrow{rr} & & V \arrow{dl} \\
M \arrow{rr} & & N\arrow[crossing over, leftarrow]{uu}\\
\end{tikzcd}


\begin{tikzpicture}[commutative diagrams/every diagram]
\node (P0) at (90:2.8cm) 
  {$X\otimes (Y\otimes (Z\otimes T))$};
\node (P1) at (90+72:2.5cm) 
  {$X\otimes ((Y\otimes Z)\otimes T))$} ;
\node (P2) at (90+2*72:2.5cm) 
  {\makebox[5ex][r]{$(X\otimes (Y\otimes Z))\otimes T$}};
\node (P3) at (90+3*72:2.5cm) 
  {\makebox[5ex][l]{$((X\otimes Y)\otimes Z)\otimes T$}};
\node (P4) at (90+4*72:2.5cm) 
  {$(X\otimes Y)\otimes (Z\otimes T)$};
\begin{scope}[commutative diagrams/.cd, every arrow, every label]
\draw (P0) to[bend right] node[swap] {$1\otimes\phi$} (P1);
\draw (P1) to[bend right] node[swap] {$\phi$} ([xshift=-15pt]P2.north west);
\draw ([xshift=-10pt]P2.south west) to[bend right] node[swap] {$\phi\otimes 1$} ([xshift=15pt]P3.south east);
\draw ([xshift=25pt]P3.north east) to[bend right] node[swap] {$\phi$} (P4);
\draw (P4) to[bend right] node[swap] {$\phi$} (P0);
\draw (P0) to[bend left=60] ([xshift=-20pt]P2.north);
\end{scope}
\draw[white,-,line width=8pt] (P1) to[bend left] ([xshift=25pt]P3.north);
\begin{scope}[commutative diagrams/.cd, every arrow, every label]
\draw (P1) to[bend left] ([xshift=25pt]P3.north);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the other requirement (an arrow from a node to a label placed on an arrow between to other nodes), a little example (again, `swap` was used to change the label position):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[commutative diagrams/every diagram]
\node (a) at (0,0)  {A};
\node (b) at (3,0) {$B$} ;
\node (c) at (0,-3) {$C$};
\begin{scope}[commutative diagrams/.cd, every arrow, every label]
\draw (a) to[bend right] node[swap] (aux) {$f$} (b);
\draw (c) to[bend right] node[swap] (aux) {$g$} (aux);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful! I've posted another minimal example combining several commands to get similar results, that I came to earlier but posted after you already edited your answer. For the example you posted, node to label arrow, I see this depends on order in which arrows are drawn, yes? Can you advise how to do this in the example I posted in the edited question?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the package *gastex* (part of the standard distribution).
See
http://www.lsv.ens-cachan.fr/~gastin/gastex/ for more details.

Look in particular at these two examples to test whether *gastex* would suit your needs.

http://www.lsv.ens-cachan.fr/~gastin/gastex/diagram.html

http://www.lsv.ens-cachan.fr/~gastin/gastex/more.html

Comment: I am getting good success with tikzpicture now. This way I can specify which node connects where. Working from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56743/how-to-draw-commutative-diagrams-in-tikz Can this sort of thing be done in tikz-cd, and what about drawing arrows going from a node to a label or changing side of arrow on which label is shown?

Comment: @user34902 all things you mention in your comments can be done with `tikz-cd`. Wouldn't it be better if you edit your question adding exactly what are you trying to achieve?