# Condensation of Digraphs in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, nodes

**How can I create a condensation of a directed graph in Tikz?**

**Goal 1**
The left is a directed graph, digraph, while the right is its condensation, source is page 183 of Handbook of Graph Theory. Aspiring discussion on this in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29790538#29790538).

[image]

**Goal 2** The same as above but with simpler example.

[image]

*Trial 2*

[image]

*MWE 2*

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm, y=2cm]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw, circle, fill=white, inner sep=3pt,minimum size=18pt] 
%1
\draw (0,0) node(1111){1};
\draw (1,0) node(2222){2};
%2 
\draw (3,0) node(1){1};
\draw (4,0) node(111){1};
\draw (5,0) node(2){2};
\draw (6,0) node(222){2};
\draw (7,0) node(3){3};

\draw[->](1)--(111);
\draw[<->](111)--(2);
\draw[->](2)--(222);
\draw[<->](222)--(3);

\node[left] at (0.8,-0.5) {(a)};
\node[left] at (5.2,-0.5) {(b)};
%-----------

%1
\draw (0,-1) node(1111){1};
\draw (1,-1) node(2222){2};
%2 
\draw (3,-1) node(1){1};
\draw (4,-1) node(111){1};
\draw (5,-1) node(2){2};
\draw (6,-1) node(222){2};
\draw (7,-1) node(3){3};

\draw[->](1)--(111);
\draw[<->](111)--(2);
\draw[->](2)--(222);
\draw[<->](222)--(3);

\node[left] at (0.8,-1.5) {(a)$^*$};
\node[left] at (5.2,-1.5) {(b)$^*$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

*Perhaps relevant thread*

1. [Creating a digraph with formulas instead of nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127597/creating-a-digraph-with-formulas-instead-of-nodes)

Comment: Please make your code compilable. Are you trying to draw D* or part of D? I don't really understand the question right now.

Comment: What are you trying to put a circle around exactly? I don't understand how the image at the top relates to the image you posted for your incomplete code.

Comment: @cfr I am trying to put that kind of hover circle-squares around $1<->2$ and $2<->3$. I want to stress that $S_1={1,2}$ and $S_2={2,3}$ as shown [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gd0Kq.png). It is a mistake to have circles around (a) and (b).

Comment: Maybe you could draw what you mean in some GUI application? And please complete your code.

Comment: @cfr updated: more accessible with Goal 1 and Goal 2 where Goal 2 was tried to be simpler, the hover square-circle drawn [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NA9Qs.png).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you refuse to post compilable code, but whatever.

Anyway, for something like that, I'd use `fit` to draw the boundaries around 2+ nodes. And I'd use a chain or the TikZ graphs stuff for the graph itself.

For example, with a simple chain (no real need for a graph here):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=main going right, every on chain/.append style={circle, draw}]
  \node [on chain] {1};
  \node [on chain, join={by ->}] {1};
  \node [on chain, join={by <->}] {2};
  \node [on chain, join={by ->}] {2};
  \node [on chain, join={by <->}] {3};
  \foreach \i/\j in {2/3,4/5}
  \node [fit=(main-\i) (main-\j), draw, rounded corners] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: chain + fit]

Or as a graph:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, graphs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph [grow right, nodes={draw, circle}, /tikz/every label/.append style={label distance=10pt}] {
    a/"1" -> 1 <-> 2[label=below:(b)*] -> b/"2" <-> 3
  };
  \foreach \i/\j in {1/2,b/3}
  \node [fit=(\i) (\j), draw, rounded corners] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: graph + fit]

Comment: I like the first approach +1, no need to get LuaLatex working as in second. On the first: how can you add the two captions below two graphs with b) and b)*? [Code](http://pastebin.com/MPLPCGyP) and [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/q302D.png): the left is the digraph while the right is the condensed graph.

Comment: @hhh The second doesn't require LuaTeX either. I used pdfTeX for both.

Comment: For the `b` or `b*`, you can use the `label=below:` for one of the nodes just as in the second case. This bit is no different which is why I only demonstrated it in one of the two.

Comment: For the second, how can I specify the position of (b)* to be on the right of (b)? [Picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/krQZA.png). I.e. two graphs side-by-side.

Comment: On the second, got the captions and graphs placed to correct positions with scope: [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6G1Yk.png) and originating from our discussion with [Alan](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29852199#29852199). Thank you for helping!

Comment: Was about to look at this @hhh. Glad you sorted it!

Answer (score 2):

The rework of cfr's graphs solution with scope to place the two graphs side-by-side, originating from our discussion with [Alan](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29852199#29852199).

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph [grow right, nodes={draw, circle}, /tikz/every label/.append style={label distance=5pt}] {
a/"1" -> 1[label=above:$S_1$] <-> 2[label=below:(b) $x_1+x_1x_2+x_2x_3$] -> b/"2"[label=above:$S_2$] <-> 3
};
\foreach \i/\j in {1/2,b/3}
\node [fit=(\i) (\j), draw, rounded corners] {};

\begin{scope}[xshift=.5\linewidth]
\graph [grow right, nodes={draw, circle}, /tikz/every label/.append style={label distance=5pt}] {
1 -> b/$S_1$[label=below:(b)* ] -> c/$S_2$
};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

*P.s. `\usetikzlibrary{fit, graphs}` needed to be in your preamble, see the solution by cfr.*